# Android 2.x XML rotated drawable, moves in wrong direction

Tags: android, xml, rotation, drawable, seekbar

I have a problem with a custom XML drawable that I have rotated by 135 degrees.

The drawable is used as the thumb in a SeekBar layout component.

This works fine on Android 4, but on Android 2.x, the thumb heads off at a 135 degree angle, instead of following the SeekBar orientation. Here is the drawable that I am setting as the thumb:

```
<item>
    <rotate android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_basic_shape"
        android:visible="true"
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135" />
</item>
```

I suspect it is related to the way Android 2.x handles references in layered drawables, but is there a way to fix it, preferably in XML?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQVtz.png) is an image with the red circle indicating where the thumb *should* be, and the red arrow indicating the direction the thumb is moving in, as I drag the slider.

[EDIT]

The first answer given below states that I need to create a separate persistent rotate animation and apply it to my thumb drawable. There are loads of examples when rotating a View or similar GUI elements, but in this case I want to rotate a drawable that is *part* of a GUI SeekBar element, and it presents some additional problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a persistant rotate animation to do that and have a full 2.x compatibility.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Doing a Google search on "android persistent rotate animation" turns up nothing, however, and it isn't a concept I'm familiar with, care to elaborate?

Comment: It's a common trick to make persistant effect on old Android devices. You create an animation with a duration of 0 and a android:repeatCount property to infinite. You can look at this link about animation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: It seems this isn't possible using only XML - I will need to create an animation "set" and apply it to the drawable via onCreate() at run-time. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I'm not seeing the "easy" part, I have to admit, since the SeekBar class apparently does not implement getThumb(), which is what I need to rotate.

Comment: I have been trying for many hours now, but the solution seems to elude me. The main crux seems to be that I want to rotate an XML-defined drawable, not a View or Bitmap.

The documentation and examples given for this case are lackluster at best. Could I convince you to post some example code?